# Loop through a DataGridView in reverse order

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

im using this code which works perfectly and loops from the start of the gridview to the end, I need it to do it the other way (starting at the last row and working back to the first)

cheers

```
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i2++)
{
    DataGridViewRow rows = dataGridView1.Rows[i2];

    MetaWeblogClient blogClient = new MetaWeblogClient();
    blogClient.NewPost((rows.Cells["imageurl"].Value).ToString(),
                       (rows.Cells["title"].Value).ToString(), 
                       (rows.Cells["videourl"].Value).ToString());
    (rows.Cells["done"].Value) = "yes";
    blogClient.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I posted the code exactly as it should read to iterate backwards and some improvements syntactically.  The null reference exception is explained below my code example.

Comment: If you're getting a null reference exception when you reverse the array iteration, please tell us the line on which it is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards should be easy. Have you tried something like this?

**Update**: Because its not clear where you're getting the null reference exception, perhaps you should wrap your call to the row's Cells property in a null check:

```
for (int i2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--) { 

  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i2];

  // Check for null value in row
  if (row != null && row.Cells["done"] != null) {
      row.Cells["done"].Value = "yes"
  } 
}
```

Comment: i tried a couple of things and it said what yours does, object not set etc

Comment: @mxadam where exactly is the error being thrown, his `for` loop is the correct way to do this.  My guess is you do not have a value in one of the `cells` you are adding in `blogClient.NewPost()`

Comment: it works fine as I posted, as soon as I paste this code I get the null error

Answer (score 1):

I think if you clean up the code a bit you will likely find the problem a bit easier.

Your naming is really hard to follow as well so I will do my best to comment this to highlight changes:

```
for (int i2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--)
{
    //Don't name a singular item with a plural name -- rows should be row
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i2];

    //MetaWeblogClient implements IDisposable so we can wrap it in a using statement
    using (MetaWeblogClient blogClient = new MetaWeblogClient())
    {
        //You do not need the parenthesis around the values
        blogClient.NewPost(row.Cells["imageurl"].Value.ToString(),
                           row.Cells["title"].Value.ToString(), 
                           row.Cells["videourl"].Value.ToString());
        row.Cells["done"].Value = "yes";
    }
    //blogClient is automatically disposed of here because of the using statement
}
```

If you are receiving a `NullReferenceException` at this point it is likely because there is no data in one of the rows as you iterate through the grid, or one of your column names is incorrect.  You can identify this type of error easily by stepping through the code in the debugger and watching each value change as you go through.

Comment: Good answer. Would it make sense to also add a null check on `row.Cells["done"]` ?

Comment: @mxadam you need to post the exact line that is throwing the null error, as well as the full error it is throwing for us to help you further.  Just telling us there is an error doesn't help.  *what is null*, *What is the exact error message you are getting*.  Help me help you ;)

Comment: imageurl is null, same as title and videourl. does it strait away, doesnt even get through 1 instance. as said my first loop works fine so its the loop. weird